# Issue with Print in Media Queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing, media-queries

**Code:**

HTML

```
    <input type="button" onclick="functionPrint()"  value="Print"/>
```

Javascript

```
    function functionPrint()
    {    
    var dydiv = document.createElement('div');
    dydiv.id='printcontent';
    mydiv.innerHTML="HI";
     window.print();   
    }
```

CSS

```
    #printcontent{
          display: none;
    }

        @media print {
            body * {
               display: none;
            }
            #printcontent, #printcontent * {
               display: block !important;
            }
            #printcontent {
               position: absolute;
               left: 0;
               top: 0;
            }
        }
```

**Update:**

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/Ryh3G/4/

I'm printing a dynamic div using the media queries. It is printing white page. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: change the `mydiv.innerHTML = "HI";` into `dydiv.innerHTML = "HI";`.

Comment: changed, but it is printing white page.

Answer (score 1):

Here, Undefined variable `mydiv`, use `dydiv`

Comment: Thanks even after, it is printing white page?

Comment: Thanks, Maulik. But I don't want to open the window?

Comment: I think you may not print without open print dialog. Please search you may find.

Comment: uframe?.. Do you means iframe? how?

Answer (score 0):

Please change function as shown below

```
function functionPrint(){  
  var dydiv = document.createElement('div');
  dydiv.id='printcontent';
  dydiv.innerHTML="HI";
  window.print();   
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, i have changed and now it is printing white page?plz help

Answer (score 0):

If body * as you have in your css reprinted is display:none, then the page will be printed empty. #printcontent is not outside of the body since the body encompasses all of the page. Instead be more specific with your print css. Look at Boilerplate's print media query for a good starting point.

```
 @media print {
        body * {
           display: none; // THIS WILL HIDE ALL CONTENT BETWEEN THE BODY TAGS so your page will be empty.
        }
        #printcontent, #printcontent * {
           display: block !important;
        }
        #printcontent {
           position: absolute;
           left: 0;
           top: 0;
        }
    }
```